# Write the inequality $\mathbf a < \mathbf b$ with unit vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

Say I have the vectors $\mathbf{a}\in  \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf b\in \mathbb R^3$, and I write
\begin{align}
\mathbf a &< \mathbf b\tag 1\\
a_j &< b_j \qquad j = 1,2,3 \tag 2
\end{align}

My question:

Is it correct to write the inequality $(1)$ with unit vectors? I mean the following, if
\begin{align}
\mathbf a &= \hat e_1 a_1 + \hat e_2 a_2 \tag 3 +\hat e_3 a_3\\
\mathbf b &= \hat e_1 b_1 + \hat e_2 b_2 +\hat e_3 b_3\tag 4
\end{align}
Is $\mathbf a < \mathbf b$ equivalent to the following
\begin{align}
\hat e_1 a_1 + \hat e_2 a_2 +\hat e_3 a_3&< \hat e_1 b_1 + \hat e_2 b_2 +\hat e_3 b_3\tag 5\\
&\iff \\
\hat e_1 (a_1 < b_1) + \hat e_2 (a_2 &< b_2) + \hat e_3 (a_3 < b_3) \tag 6\\
&\iff \\
\hat e_1 (a_1 - b_1 < 0) + \hat e_2 (a_2 - b_2 &< 0) + \hat e_3 (a_3-b_3<0)\tag 7
\end{align}
?

Comment: Never heard of such thing (or such notation). What do you even mean by $\hat e_1 (a_1 < b_1) + \hat e_2 (a_2 < b_2) + \hat e_3 (a_3 < b_3)$???

Comment: This question is probably better suited to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Your (5), (6), (7) is not mathematical notation.  Instead, write

\begin{align}
\hat e_1 a_1 + \hat e_2 a_2 +\hat e_3 a_3&< \hat e_1 b_1 + \hat e_2 b_2 +\hat e_3 b_3\tag 5\\
&\iff \\
a_1 < b_1 \quad\text{and}\quad a_2 &< b_2 \quad\text{and}\quad  a_3 < b_3 \tag 6\\
&\iff \\
 a_1 - b_1 < 0 \quad\text{and}\quad  a_2 - b_2 &< 0 \quad\text{and}\quad  a_3-b_3<0\tag 7
\end{align}

---

Also note: You should state that (2) is the definition of (1), since it is not something that is commonly used.